# Laravel 8: create new user programmatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I'd like to create a new user in programmatically way, calling a webhook from a form of another website.

I added the route in web.php;

I added in the Controller a function copying the `create` function in `RegisterController.php` of Auth

```
public function add_user(Request $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I added the route under `$except` of `class VerifyCsrfToken`

(even if is not working and I commented, just for testing, the

```
     // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

in `Kernel.php`

but on online test tool I receive a "405 Method Not Allowed".

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's your route definition?

Comment: maybe you use wrong http method

Comment: very basic, Route::post('/add-user', 'HomeController@add_user')->name('add_user');

Answer (score 1):

In your routes file you are using `Route::get()` and then sending a post request. Try using `Route::post()` instead.

For testing you could use `Route::any()` to allow get and post requests.